# Error running Windows CE sample code

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I have this sample code for disable/enable WIFI in Windows CE.

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SetDevicePower(string pvDevice, int dwDeviceFlags, DevicePowerState DeviceState);

private enum DevicePowerState : int
{
    Unspecified = -1,
    D0 = 0, // Full On: full power, full functionality 
    D1, // Low Power On: fully functional at low power/performance 
    D2, // Standby: partially powered with automatic wake 
    D3, // Sleep: partially powered with device initiated wake 
    D4, // Off: unpowered 
}

private const int POWER_NAME = 0x00000001;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

//Utilities.WiFi.FindDriverKey() is simply a function that returns the whole registry key name
//of the key containing the NDIS MINIPORT class GUID defined in he SDK’s pm.h:

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string driver = Utilities.WiFi.FindDriverKey();
    SetDevicePower(driver, POWER_NAME, DevicePowerState.D0);
}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string driver = Utilities.WiFi.FindDriverKey();
    SetDevicePower(driver, POWER_NAME, DevicePowerState.D4);
}


private static string FindDriverKey()
{
    string ret = string.Empty;

    //#define PMCLASS_NDIS_MINIPORT           TEXT("{98C5250D-C29A-4985-AE5F-AFE5367E5006}") 
    //(From "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\PocketPC\Include\Armv4i\pm.h") 
    string WiFiDriverClass = "{98C5250D-C29A-4985-AE5F-AFE5367E5006}";

    foreach (string tmp in Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Power\\State", false).GetValueNames())
    {
        if (tmp.Contains(WiFiDriverClass))
        {
            ret = tmp;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

However, I get this error:

> The name 'Utilities' does not exist in the current context

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably because `FindDriverKey()` used to be in a `Utilities` class or namespace.  Just drop the `Utilities.Wifi` before the call to `FindDriverKey()` and you should be all set.  Alternatively, you could create a Utilities namespace, then create a static class called `Wifi` and drop the `FindDriverKey()` function inside the `Wifi` class.